# Kotlin: Reified generics don't seem to work right for hash/equals comparisons

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I have a map of `KClass` to `Int`. I then have a function which has a reified generic type. I'd then expect the following situation, thus, to give me the `Int` associated with `Boolean::class`

```
val kclassToInt = mapOf(Boolean::class to 1, Byte::class to 1, Short::class to 2)

inline fun <reified T> myExpectations() =
        assertEquals(1, kclassToInt.getRaw(T::class), "Why doesn't it work? :'(")
```

I'm greeted with `Why doesn't it work? :'(. Expected <1>, actual <null>.` from a call to it like this `myExpectations<Boolean>()`.

I then tried to use `.java` off, so I was using Java's `Class` rather than Kotlin's `KClass`.

```
val classToInt = mapOf(Boolean::class.java to 1, Byte::class.java to 1, Short::class.java to 2)

inline fun <reified T : Any> anotherExpectation() =
        assertEquals(1, classToInt.getRaw(T::class.java))
```

This time I was again greeted by assertion error: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <1>, actual <null>.`

Finally I tried using `.javaClass` rather than `.java`:

```
val javaClassToInt = mapOf(Boolean::class.javaClass to 1, Byte::class.javaClass to 1, Short::class.javaClass to 2)

inline fun <reified T> pleaseWork() =
        assertEquals(1, javaClassToInt.getRaw(T::class.javaClass))
```

This time it was really strange. I was greeted with this: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <1>, actual <2>.` This seems to be because all `.javaClass` refer to `KClassImpl`.

Finally I resorted to what I didn't want to do, use `.qualifiedName`:

```
val qnToInt = mapOf(Boolean::class.qualifiedName to 1, Byte::class.qualifiedName to 1, Short::class.qualifiedName to 2)

inline fun <reified T> iKnowItWorks() =
        assertEquals(1, qnToInt.getRaw(T::class.qualifiedName))
```

Which of course works and is what I use in my actual use case: https://github.com/Jire/kotmem/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jire/kotmem/Process.kt

Comment: How do you "print `type`"? Can you paste the full sample? What do you mean by "it shows"?

Comment: The answer is yes. Now what's the question ;-?

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov I printed via `println`

@DuncanMcGregor The question has been updated.

The question now contains a link to the actual use case.

Comment: I still have no idea how to reproduce the problem you're describing. If I add `println(type)` to the code above and call `read<Boolean>(0L)` for example, I get `class kotlin.Boolean` as expected. Can you please provide the full source code which results in `KClassImpl` printed and any other information required to reproduce this?

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov My full project source code is in the question although I don't think I am clear enough. This question has a unit test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987746/are-kotlins-reified-types-incorrect-for-primitives-on-the-jvm

Comment: That question concerns how exactly do class literals work for primitive Kotlin classes. This question, on the other hand, is titled "Reflection exposes KClassImpl" which is once again what I'm trying to reproduce. Your project code doesn't have any `println`s, and `println(type)` works as expected, that's why I was asking you to specify what exactly did you do to make "KClassImpl" appear on the screen.

Comment: Anyway, most likely you did `println(type.javaClass)` which would print `KClassImpl` regardless of how primitive class literals would work in Kotlin, because the Java class of the *variable* named `type` is an implementation of `KClass` (because `type`'s type is `KClass`...) which happens to be `KClassImpl` at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the key types in your Map are `KClass` instances for the primitive types (Java int rather than Integer). The reified type in the function is the `KClass` instance for the boxed type (Integer), as seen in [Are Kotlin's reified types incorrect for primitives on the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987746/are-kotlins-reified-types-incorrect-for-primitives-on-the-jvm)

Whilst these two `KClass`s print as the same thing, they are not equal, so your lookup fails.

Comment: Thus I should map the Java boxed type's `KClass` (e.g. `java.lang.Boolean::class`) to what I need. Then I can access easily using `T::class`. (I did this here: https://github.com/Jire/kotmem/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jire/kotmem/DataType.kt )

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you've written something like `println(type.javaClass)` which may seem to make sense, but actually doesn't because it always prints `class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl`, since that is the internal implementation class of the `KClass` interface.

Why does `type.javaClass` work that way? `javaClass` is an extension property which gets a runtime Java class of any value passed to it as a receiver. Its signature is:

```
val <T : Any> T.javaClass: Class<T>
```

`type` is a perfectly valid value of type `KClass<T>`, so `type.javaClass`'s resulting type is `Class<KClass<T>>`. This is already almost entirely meaningless unless you want to introspect symbols of the `KClass` implementation class. Since `type` is a `KClassImpl` instance at runtime, `type.javaClass` is effectively a `Class` instance representing the class named `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl`.

This is a bit confusing and definitely not what you wanted to do. If you want to print a class instance to the screen, you can just call `println(type)`. If you want to obtain a Java `Class` instance corresponding to the `KClass` instance you have, you can use the `java` extension property: `type.java`. `java`'s signature is:

```
val <T : Any> KClass<T>.java: Class<T>
```

So if `type` is a `KClass<T>`, then `type.java` is a `Class<T>`.

Comment: In this example https://gist.github.com/Jire/63da3cf482bb9f5d4749 where I call read like `val example: Int = read(123)` it fails the first two if statements and the last succeeds. This is what does not make sense to me.

Comment: Then please ask exactly that next time, because I was trying to figure out why are you observing `KClassImpl` somewhere, based on the way this question is titled and worded. If you're no longer observing `KClassImpl`, then please rephrase the question to stop confusing people who are trying to help. Anyway, I think Duncan's question and the answer there should help you now.

Comment: First and foremost I want to thank you for helping me with this. Your answer to @DuncanMcGregor did not work even if mapping for example `Boolean::class.java` to `1` and then querying for `T::class.java`. I have since updated my question and it should be more clear.